# Indexing in MongoDB for a complex query

Tags: mongodb, indexing, mongodb-query

I have the following query :

```js
db.restaurant_service_orders.find({order_settlement_status :1,order_status : {"$in" : [6,4]}, created_at : {"$lte" :  ISODate("2015-04-10T00:00:00.000Z"), "$gte" :  ISODate("2015-03-10T00:00:00.000Z")}})
```

I have created the following indexes :

```js
index({created_at:1 }),

index({order_settlement_status: 1, order_status: 1, created_at: 1})
```

But on `query.explain()`

I get index on created_at and not on the my other index.

Please suggest appropriate indexes for the above , and explain the reasons:

The explain plan for:

```
db.restaurant_service_orders.find({order_settlement_status :1,order_status : {"$in" : [6,4]}, created_at : {"$lte" :  ISODate("2015-04-10T00:00:00.000Z"), "$gte" :  ISODate("2014-03-10T00:00:00.000Z")}}).explain()
```

> {     "cursor" : "BtreeCursor created_at_1",  "isMultiKey" : false,   "n"
>   : 182222,     "nscannedObjects" : 209645,     "nscanned" : 209645,
>     "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 210453,     "nscannedAllPlans" : 210756,
>     "scanAndOrder" : false,     "indexOnly" : false,    "nYields" : 0,
>     "nChunkSkips" : 0,  "millis" : 815,     "indexBounds" : {       "created_at"
>   : [           [
>                 ISODate("2014-03-10T00:00:00Z"),
>                 ISODate("2015-04-10T00:00:00Z")             ]       ]   },  "server" : "Junaids-MacBook-Pro.local:27017" }

The explain plan for with hint :

```
 db.restaurant_service_orders.find({order_settlement_status :1,order_status : {"$in" : [6,4]}, created_at : {"$lte" :  ISODate("2015-04-10T00:00:00.000Z"), "$gte" :  ISODate("2014-03-10T00:00:00.000Z")}}).hint({order_settlement_status :1,order_status : 1, created_at : 1}).explain()
```

> {     "cursor" : "BtreeCursor
>   order_settlement_status_1_order_status_1_created_at_1 multi",
>     "isMultiKey" : false,   "n" : 182222,   "nscannedObjects" : 182222,
>     "nscanned" : 182223,    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 182222,
>     "nscannedAllPlans" : 182223,    "scanAndOrder" : false,     "indexOnly" :
>   false,    "nYields" : 2,  "nChunkSkips" : 0,  "millis" : 540,
>     "indexBounds" : {       "order_settlement_status" : [           [
>                 1,
>                 1           ]       ],      "order_status" : [          [
>                 4,
>                 4           ],          [
>                 6,
>                 6           ]       ],      "created_at" : [            [
>                 ISODate("2014-03-10T00:00:00Z"),
>                 ISODate("2015-04-10T00:00:00Z")             ]       ]   },  "server" : "Junaids-MacBook-Pro.local:27017" }

Comment: Did you try to force it to use the 2nd index with [`cursor.hint(index)`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.hint/#cursor.hint)?

Comment: @Philipp : Doesn't it mean that index with created_at is more optimised that with index on order_settlement_status: 1, order_status: 1, created_at: 1 ?

Comment: Mongo Engine evaluates indexes before query execution. It is not showing in explain plan because it thinks that 2nd index is not useful as results can be fetched using 1st index. In other words 1st index suffice the need. Still you are absolutely sure that 2nd index will improve the perf. then use hint option.

Comment: @zooney Please try it and see if it has better or worse performance. Then we can tell if it is a fluke of the query optimizer or if the second index does indeed not help (maybe because there is something in that query which can not use indexes).

Comment: @Philipp : Just read here, http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-multikey/ Its a limitation of mongo . It can have only one array index

Comment: @zooney But you only have one array in the fields covered by your index, so this limitation doesn't apply in this case. Also, when this would be a problem, you would get the error message when inserting the document.

Comment: @Philipp : Is there anything wrong with the index creation? Do you think it is appropriate for this query ?

Comment: @zooney We can not help you when you don't cooperate. Please try to force use of the second index with `.hint` and `.explain` to analyze it.

Comment: @Philipp : When I do hint and explain, it gives better results with less scanned objects

Comment: Please post the explain plans. The index used for a query is chosen based on a race between candidate indexes. Seeing the explain will help us understand how the `created_at` index won.

Comment: @wdberkeley:check the query plan above in the edited question

Comment: @wdberkeley : Any explanation for the query plan?